# How do you add a link to the end of an html quiz after the quiz displays the results?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the HTML for my HTML quiz:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>HTML Quiz</title>
        <style>
          body {
            background-color: #60c3fe;
          }
          div#test {
            border: #6c7bd8 3px solid;
            padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 50%;
          }
          button {
            background-color: #ffcc00;
          }
        </style>
        <script src="HTMLQuiz.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2 id="test_status"></h2>
        <div id="test">
          <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="document.location='QuizHome.html'">Home</button>
        <button onclick="document.location='HTMLQuiz.html'">Reset</button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

This is the JavaScript for my HTML Quiz:

```
    var pos = 0;
    var correct = 0;
    var test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD;
    
    var questions = [
      {
        question:
          "How many sections or elements does the basic structure of any HTML document consist of?",
        a: "1",
        b: "4",
        c: "2",
        d: "3",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the HTML id attribute used for?",
        a: "To the name of an element",
        b: "To specify a class for an HTML element",
        c: "To define a variable",
        d: "To specify a unique id for an HTML element",
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the syntax for a numbered list?",
        a: "&#60ol&#62",
        b: "&#60ul&#62",
        c: "&#60li&#62",
        d: "&#60dl&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "What does HTML stand for?",
        a: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
        b: "Hyper Tool Text Language",
        c: "Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language",
        d: "Home Tool Markup Language",
        answer: "C",
      },
      {
        question: "Who is making the Web standards?",
        a: "Apple",
        b: "The World Wide Web Consortium",
        c: "Google",
        d: "Microsoft",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "Choose the correct HTML element for the largest heading:",
        a: "&#60head&#62",
        b: "&#60h1&#62",
        c: "&#60h6&#62",
        d: "&#60heading&#62",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "How many header elements are there?",
        a: "6",
        b: "1",
        c: "7",
        d: "4",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "Which character is used to indicate an end tag?",
        a: "/",
        b: ">",
        c: "*",
        d: ".",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "Which tag defines a hyperlink?",
        a: "&#60link&#62",
        b: "&#60hyperlink&#62",
        c: "&#60href&#62",
        d: "&#60a&#62",
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "Which of these is the syntax for class?",
        a: "name.class",
        b: "classname.",
        c: ".classname",
        d: "class.name",
        answer: "C",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the syntax for a bulleted list?",
        a: "&#60lo&#62",
        b: "&#60lu&#62",
        c: "&#60ul&#62",
        d: "&#60ol&#62",
        answer: "C",
      },
      {
        question: "Which of these is the tag for a table?",
        a: "&#60table&#62",
        b: "&#60tr&#62",
        c: "&#60th&#62",
        d: "&#60td&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "Which HTML element defines the title of a document?",
        a: "&#60title&#62",
        b: "&#60meta&#62",
        c: "&#60head&#62",
        d: "&#60header&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the correct HTML for making a checkbox?",
        a: "&#60check&#62",
        b: '&#60input type="check"&#62',
        c: "&#60checkbox&#62",
        d: '&#60input type="checkbox"&#62',
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the correct HTML for adding a background color of blue?",
        a: '&#60body bg="blue"&#62',
        b: '&#60body style="background-color:blue;"&#62',
        c: "&#60background&#62blue&#60/background&#62",
        d: "&#60style background-color&#62blue&#60/style&#62",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "Which tag defines a paragraph?",
        a: "&#60label&#62",
        b: "&#60section&#62",
        c: "&#60paragraph&#62",
        d: "&#60p&#62",
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What does a &#60footer&#62 tag typically contain?",
        a: "Copyright and authorship information",
        b: "Contact information",
        c: "Sitemap and back to top links",
        d: "All of the above",
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the &#60div&#62 tag used for in HTML?",
        a: "As a link to a URL",
        b: "As a container for HTML elements",
        c: "As a header",
        d: "As a paragraph",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "What tag is used to embed an image to an HTML page?",
        a: "&#60src&#62",
        b: "&#60image&#62",
        c: "&#60img&#62",
        d: "&#60link&#62",
        answer: "C",
      },
      {
        question: "What header is used to define details of a topic?",
        a: "&#60h3&#62",
        b: "&#60h1&#62",
        c: "&#60h2&#62",
        d: "&#60h5&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the correct HTML for making a drop-down list?",
        a: "&#60list&#62",
        b: "&#60select&#62",
        c: '&#60input type="list"&#62',
        d: '&#60input type="dropdown"&#62',
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the correct HTML for inserting a background image?",
        a: '&#60body style="background-image:url(background.gif)"&#62',
        b: '&#60body bg="background.gif"&#62',
        c: '&#60body background="background.gif"&#62',
        d: '&#60background img="background.gif"&#62',
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What does an HTML comment start and end with?",
        a: "&#60! and &#62",
        b: "// and .",
        c: "// and &#62",
        d: "&#60 and &#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "Which of these elements are all &#60table&#62 elements?",
        a: "&#60table&#62 &#60tr&#62 &#60tt&#62",
        b: "&#60table&#62 &#60tr&#62 &#60td&#62",
        c: "&#60head&#62 &#60body&#62 &#60td&#62",
        d: "&#60table&#62 &#60head&#62 &#60tfoot&#62",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "Which HTML element defines important text?",
        a: "&#60strong&#62",
        b: "&#60i&#62",
        c: "&#60important&#62",
        d: "&#60b&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
    ];
    
    function get(x) {
      return document.getElementById(x);
    }
    
    function renderQuestion() {
      test = get("test");
      if (pos >= questions.length) {
        test.innerHTML =
          "<h2>You got " +
          correct +
          " of " +
          questions.length +
          " questions correct.</h2>";
        get("test_status").innerHTML = "Test completed!";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
      }
      get("test_status").innerHTML =
        "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length + ":";
    
      question = questions[pos].question;
      chA = questions[pos].a;
      chB = questions[pos].b;
      chC = questions[pos].c;
      chD = questions[pos].d;
      test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
    
      test.innerHTML +=
        "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " +
        chA +
        "</label><br>";
      test.innerHTML +=
        "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " +
        chB +
        "</label><br>";
      test.innerHTML +=
        "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " +
        chC +
        "</label><br>";
      test.innerHTML +=
        "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> " +
        chD +
        "</label><br><br>";
      test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
    }
    
    function checkAnswer() {
      choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
      for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        if (choices[i].checked) {
          choice = choices[i].value;
        }
      }
      if (choice == questions[pos].answer) {
        correct++;
      }
      pos++;
      renderQuestion();
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion);
```

I have a line of code, `<button onclick="document.location='HTMLAnswerKey.html'">HTML Quiz Answer Key</button>`, that I'd like to add so that a button that links to the answer key of my html quiz will be displayed after the quiz displays the results [image: Results Page]. I want the button to be within the div container directly below the, "You got 0 of 25 questions correct!" On which file, and where in the file, would I add this line of code to have a button appear after my quiz is completed?

Comment: You can add it in your HTML file where it should to be shown, then implement the show/hide button in JS

Answer (score 1):

Add the link to the *HTML* right where you want it to be and then set it to `display: none;` so it will not be present in the DOM. Then in your *javascript* where the quiz is wrapped up and the window shows the score, add a line that changes the style of your link elements `display` from ***none*** to ***block*** `get("after-quiz-link").style.display = block;`. You will also have to add logic that hides that link should the quiz be active as well, ***I think*** that line can be added directly below the conditional that displays the score.

```js
      if (pos >= questions.length) {
        test.innerHTML =
          "<h2>You got " +
          correct +
          " of " +
          questions.length +
          " questions correct.</h2>";
        get("test_status").innerHTML = "Test completed!";
        get("after-quiz-link").style.display = block;
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
      }
      //--> if the quiz is not finished keep hiding the link
      get("after-quiz-link").style.display = block;
```

html: If you want the link to be displayed in the white area directly below the "You got 0 of 25 questions correct!", move the link into the `<div id='test'>` just below the  `<button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>` element.

```html
      <body>
        <h2 id="test_status"></h2>
        <div id="test">
          <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
        </div>
        <!--/ Added Link Here /-->
        <a href="#" id="after-quiz-link">This is an added link</a>
        <button onclick="document.location='QuizHome.html'">Home</button>
        <button onclick="document.location='HTMLQuiz.html'">Reset</button>
      </body>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I decided to put the button on the same line with the other buttons, and only have the button display on the result page. I had to add a CSS for the id I set for the button link to display:none. In the JavaScript, I added, ````const quizLink = document.getElementById("after_quiz_link");
    quizLink.style.display = "inline-block";````.

Answer (score 0):

With the help from the suggestion this is what my final code for the HTML file looks like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>HTML Quiz</title>
        <style>
          body {
            background-color: #60c3fe;
          }
          div#test {
            border: #6c7bd8 3px solid;
            padding: 10px 40px 40px 40px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            width: 50%;
          }
          button {
            background-color: #ffcc00;
          }
          #after_quiz_link {
            display: none;
          }
        </style>
        <script src="HTMLQuiz.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2 id="test_status"></h2>
        <div id="test">
          <button onclick="checkAnswer()">Submit Answer</button>
        </div>
        <button onclick="document.location='QuizHome.html'">Home</button>
        <button onclick="document.location='HTMLQuiz.html'">Reset</button>
        <button
          id="after_quiz_link"
          onclick="document.location='HTMLAnswerKey.html'"
        >
          Answer Key
        </button>
      </body>
    </html>
```

The JavaScript code:

```
    var pos = 0;
    var correct = 0;
    var test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, chD;
    
    var questions = [
      {
        question:
          "How many sections or elements does the basic structure of any HTML document consist of?",
        a: "1",
        b: "4",
        c: "2",
        d: "3",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the HTML id attribute used for?",
        a: "To the name of an element",
        b: "To specify a class for an HTML element",
        c: "To define a variable",
        d: "To specify a unique id for an HTML element",
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the syntax for a numbered list?",
        a: "&#60ol&#62",
        b: "&#60ul&#62",
        c: "&#60li&#62",
        d: "&#60dl&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "What does HTML stand for?",
        a: "Hyper Text Markup Language",
        b: "Hyper Tool Text Language",
        c: "Hyperlinks and Text Markup Language",
        d: "Home Tool Markup Language",
        answer: "C",
      },
      {
        question: "Who is making the Web standards?",
        a: "Apple",
        b: "The World Wide Web Consortium",
        c: "Google",
        d: "Microsoft",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "Choose the correct HTML element for the largest heading:",
        a: "&#60head&#62",
        b: "&#60h1&#62",
        c: "&#60h6&#62",
        d: "&#60heading&#62",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "How many header elements are there?",
        a: "6",
        b: "1",
        c: "7",
        d: "4",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "Which character is used to indicate an end tag?",
        a: "/",
        b: ">",
        c: "*",
        d: ".",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "Which tag defines a hyperlink?",
        a: "&#60link&#62",
        b: "&#60hyperlink&#62",
        c: "&#60href&#62",
        d: "&#60a&#62",
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "Which of these is the syntax for class?",
        a: "name.class",
        b: "classname.",
        c: ".classname",
        d: "class.name",
        answer: "C",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the syntax for a bulleted list?",
        a: "&#60lo&#62",
        b: "&#60lu&#62",
        c: "&#60ul&#62",
        d: "&#60ol&#62",
        answer: "C",
      },
      {
        question: "Which of these is the tag for a table?",
        a: "&#60table&#62",
        b: "&#60tr&#62",
        c: "&#60th&#62",
        d: "&#60td&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "Which HTML element defines the title of a document?",
        a: "&#60title&#62",
        b: "&#60meta&#62",
        c: "&#60head&#62",
        d: "&#60header&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the correct HTML for making a checkbox?",
        a: "&#60check&#62",
        b: '&#60input type="check"&#62',
        c: "&#60checkbox&#62",
        d: '&#60input type="checkbox"&#62',
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the correct HTML for adding a background color of blue?",
        a: '&#60body bg="blue"&#62',
        b: '&#60body style="background-color:blue;"&#62',
        c: "&#60background&#62blue&#60/background&#62",
        d: "&#60style background-color&#62blue&#60/style&#62",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "Which tag defines a paragraph?",
        a: "&#60label&#62",
        b: "&#60section&#62",
        c: "&#60paragraph&#62",
        d: "&#60p&#62",
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What does a &#60footer&#62 tag typically contain?",
        a: "Copyright and authorship information",
        b: "Contact information",
        c: "Sitemap and back to top links",
        d: "All of the above",
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the &#60div&#62 tag used for in HTML?",
        a: "As a link to a URL",
        b: "As a container for HTML elements",
        c: "As a header",
        d: "As a paragraph",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "What tag is used to embed an image to an HTML page?",
        a: "&#60src&#62",
        b: "&#60image&#62",
        c: "&#60img&#62",
        d: "&#60link&#62",
        answer: "C",
      },
      {
        question: "What header is used to define details of a topic?",
        a: "&#60h3&#62",
        b: "&#60h1&#62",
        c: "&#60h2&#62",
        d: "&#60h5&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the correct HTML for making a drop-down list?",
        a: "&#60list&#62",
        b: "&#60select&#62",
        c: '&#60input type="list"&#62',
        d: '&#60input type="dropdown"&#62',
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "What is the correct HTML for inserting a background image?",
        a: '&#60body style="background-image:url(background.gif)"&#62',
        b: '&#60body bg="background.gif"&#62',
        c: '&#60body background="background.gif"&#62',
        d: '&#60background img="background.gif"&#62',
        answer: "D",
      },
      {
        question: "What does an HTML comment start and end with?",
        a: "&#60! and &#62",
        b: "// and .",
        c: "// and &#62",
        d: "&#60 and &#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
      {
        question: "Which of these elements are all &#60table&#62 elements?",
        a: "&#60table&#62 &#60tr&#62 &#60tt&#62",
        b: "&#60table&#62 &#60tr&#62 &#60td&#62",
        c: "&#60head&#62 &#60body&#62 &#60td&#62",
        d: "&#60table&#62 &#60head&#62 &#60tfoot&#62",
        answer: "B",
      },
      {
        question: "Which HTML element defines important text?",
        a: "&#60strong&#62",
        b: "&#60i&#62",
        c: "&#60important&#62",
        d: "&#60b&#62",
        answer: "A",
      },
    ];
    
    function get(x) {
      return document.getElementById(x);
    }
    
    function renderQuestion() {
      test = get("test");
      if (pos >= questions.length) {
        test.innerHTML =
          "<h2>You got " +
          correct +
          " of " +
          questions.length +
          " questions correct.</h2>";
        get("test_status").innerHTML = "Test completed!";
        const quizLink = document.getElementById("after_quiz_link");
        quizLink.style.display = "inline-block";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
      }
    
      get("test_status").innerHTML =
        "Question " + (pos + 1) + " of " + questions.length + ":";
    
      question = questions[pos].question;
      chA = questions[pos].a;
      chB = questions[pos].b;
      chC = questions[pos].c;
      chD = questions[pos].d;
      test.innerHTML = "<h3>" + question + "</h3>";
    
      test.innerHTML +=
        "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> " +
        chA +
        "</label><br>";
      test.innerHTML +=
        "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> " +
        chB +
        "</label><br>";
      test.innerHTML +=
        "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> " +
        chC +
        "</label><br>";
      test.innerHTML +=
        "<label> <input type='radio' name='choices' value='D'> " +
        chD +
        "</label><br><br>";
      test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
    }
    
    function checkAnswer() {
      choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
      for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        if (choices[i].checked) {
          choice = choices[i].value;
        }
      }
      if (choice == questions[pos].answer) {
        correct++;
      }
      pos++;
      renderQuestion();
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion);
```

[image: Screenshot of solution]